# LookupAccountSid taking +600 ms per call

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm using `GetTokenInformation` with the `TokenGroups` flags to retrieve all the groups that a particular token is part of. I'm then looping through each of the returned SIDs and using `LookupAccountSid` to grab the user name and domain. I call `LookupAccountSid` twice: the first time to grab the size of the name and domain character arrays and the second time populates the allocated `StringBuilder`s.

I'm getting very long delays. I've run ANTS to see what the issue was and found that if a user was part of 23 groups this that the entire sequence would take 15 seconds! The profiler points to the first call of LookupAccountSid and states that it was averaging 652 ms per call.

This is what the call looks like:

```
            LookupAccountSid(null, tokenGroups.Groups[i].SID, null, ref accountCount, null,
                             ref domainCount, out snu);
```

`accountCount` and `domainCount` are initialized to 0 prior to this call. In the end the call is working but this delay is way to long. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Network delays talking to the domain controller, or the DC itself, would be my guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to accurately measure time taken when running a profiler.

It is only useful when compared to all the times of other methods.

Run the call using Stopwatch as a timer without debugging info/attaching a debugger, and optimizations turned on.

**Edit:**

I have code that runs about 100 times longer when a profiler is attached (10 seconds) vs NGEN'd app (0.1 seconds).

Comment: Whew. Problem was actually fixed by something else and I thought, because the profiler was slowing this down, that the bug was still creeping around. The execution now takes around 1-2 ms! Thanks for helping me with my ignorance. :)